# Function strpos() does not return anything

Tags: php

I am trying to find http://www.facebook.com in the `$content` string below but it does not return anything. Please guide. Thanks.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/4');
$url = 'http://www.facebook.com';

$pos = strpos($content, $url);  //find position of url in string
echo $pos;
```

Comment: It might not able to find the variable `$url` value in the `$content`. Hence `strpos` would returning `FALSE` and echoing nothing.

Comment: Test for Boolean `false` on failure

Comment: What is the output of `$content`?

Comment: That graph returns a json, you can json_decode that and get ['link'].

Comment: @neeagl: $content holds {
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}

Comment: @Ak1to but you are searching for `http://www.facebook.com` which is nowhere in `$content` . And like others said, you should use json_decode and then extract ['link']

Answer (score 3):

Contents from `http://graph.facebook.com/4` came as encoded string. In this string slashes are shielded. If you use `var_dump($contents)` you will see:

```
"link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/zuck"
```

Definitely `strpos` return `false`, as `http://www.facebook.com` is not present in `$contents`.
You can use `json_decode($content)` to check what is `link` value.

Comment: Good one. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when using strpos() you need to check returned value with type because it can return 0 (when string founded at 0 position) OR false (when string not founded) 
So second case is yours. 
To check that use `var_dump()` instead `echo`